# Show a component on hover in reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs

I've created several sections with the heading of the specific content.

I want to show a short sneak preview on hovering above the different section.

Does anyone knows how to create a hoverActionHandler with conditional rendering of a react component?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can use `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` to change the state and render a component conditionally based on the value of the state.

See it in action:

- Hooks Implentation: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hover-example-hooks-0to7u
- Class Implemntation: https://codesandbox.io/s/XopkqJ5oV

Hooks:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const HoverableDiv = ({ handleMouseOver, handleMouseOut }) => {
  return (
    <div onMouseOver={handleMouseOver} onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}>
      Hover Me
    </div>
  );
};

const HoverText = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      Hovering right meow!
      <span role="img" aria-label="cat">
        
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

const HoverExample = () => {
  const [isHovering, setIsHovering] = useState(false);
  const handleMouseOver = () => {
    setIsHovering(true);
  };

  const handleMouseOut = () => {
    setIsHovering(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Hover over this div to hide/show <HoverText /> */}
      <HoverableDiv
        handleMouseOver={handleMouseOver}
        handleMouseOut={handleMouseOut}
      />
      {isHovering && <HoverText />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Class:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const HoverableDiv = React.memo(({ handleMouseOver, handleMouseOut }) => {
  return (
    <div onMouseOver={handleMouseOver} onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}>
      Hover Me
    </div>
  );
});

const HoverText = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      Hovering right meow!
      <span role="img" aria-label="cat">
        
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

class HoverExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleMouseOver = this.handleMouseOver.bind(this);
    this.handleMouseOut = this.handleMouseOut.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isHovering: false
    };
  }

  handleMouseOver() {
    this.setState(() => ({
      isHovering: true
    }));
  }

  handleMouseOut() {
    this.setState(() => ({
      isHovering: false
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* <HoverText /> gets shown when mouse is over <HoverableDiv /> */}
        <HoverableDiv
          handleMouseOver={this.handleMouseOver}
          handleMouseOut={this.handleMouseOut}
        />
        {this.state.isHovering && <HoverText />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this example. I solved the problem with this base and added some Helping functions to optimize the handling of the hover.

Comment: +1 Nice solution! I only made a slight change to explicitly set isHovering to true or false whether entering or leaving, in case the user somehow ended up outside the element without triggering the onMouseLeave.

Comment: how to keep Hovering right meow!  visible when I am hovering Hovering right meow! 

Comment: @AniruddhAgarwal you can move the `onMouseEnter`/`onMouseLeave` handlers to the container

Comment: its a great example but i have the same issue with different condition : i have more than 1 div tag, each of them has one filter icon ( with the same class ) beside of itself. so when i hover on one of them by tour way it shows all filter icons, however i want to show just its filter icon

Comment: The above code was making the hover action behave abnormally in a certain case where I had other components for example a DropDown inside the div. To solve that, I had to create different method for both the mouseEnter and the mouseLeave events and handle actions accordingly.

Comment: What about debounce or throttling ? Is this the best answer?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa, you could certainly add debouncing/throttling/requestAnimationFrame depending on your use case. This answer just illustrates the easiest logic to go about showing/hiding on hover.

Comment: This is the function I was looking for. But how can I target the div that's currently hovering?

Comment: Um, when I hover over the text, and the move my mouse over the cat text, it breaks?

Comment: Good catch @CrazyVideoGamer. I've updated the examples to be fixed now. The reason was because of the way the onMouseEnter/onMouseLeave events work: From React Docs: "The onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave events propagate from the element being left to the one being entered instead of ordinary bubbling and do not have a capture phase."

Comment: `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` caused unexpected results for me: both fired continuously whilst inside the element. For me, `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` worked perfectly for this purpose.