# How to use reactstrap popover on hover?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popover, reactstrap

I am new to the react . Here I am using a library called `reactstrap`, In which ,

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Popover, PopoverHeader, PopoverBody } from 'reactstrap';

export default class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      popoverOpen: false
    };
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      popoverOpen: !this.state.popoverOpen
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button id="Popover1" type="button">
          Launch Popover
        </Button>
        <Popover placement="bottom" isOpen={this.state.popoverOpen} target="Popover1" toggle={this.toggle}>
          <PopoverHeader>Popover Title</PopoverHeader>
          <PopoverBody>Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</PopoverBody>
        </Popover>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, Here what I am trying is when user `hover` on that button itself then only user should be able to see that `popover`. SO is there any way through which we can use this on hover itself ?

Comment: Try onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave 
as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44568861/5995973

Answer (score 11):

For this, you can use the `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` events:

```
<Button
   id="Popover1"
   type="button"
   onMouseEnter={this.onHover}
   onMouseLeave={this.onHoverLeave}
>
    Launch Popover
</Button>
```

And the methods should look like:

```
onHover() {
  this.setState({
    popoverOpen: true,
  })
}

onHoverLeave() {
  this.setState({
    popoverOpen: false,
  })
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-dl8gr?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 0):

```
Without Reactstrap using Material UI of ReactJS
Calling rowHover method :
    rowHover= (event) => {
        const rowId = event.currentTarget?.dataset?.id;
        console.log(rowId);
        this.state.popRowData = rowId;
        this.setState({ popRowData: rowId });
        this.state.anchorE1 = true;
        this.state.open = true;
      };
    
On Mouse event
                          onMouseEnter: this.rowHover, // <------- Here
                          onMouseLeave: this.handlePopoverClose
    Popover called : 
        <Popover
                id="mouse-over-popover"
                sx={{
                  pointerEvents: 'none',
                }}
                open={this.state.open}
                anchorEl={this.state.anchorE1}
                anchorOrigin={{
                  vertical: 'bottom',
                  horizontal: 'center',
                }}
                transformOrigin={{
                  vertical: 'center',
                  horizontal: 'center',
                }}
                onClose={this.handlePopoverClose}
                disableRestoreFocus
              >
                <Typography sx={{ p: 1 }}>{this.state.popRowData}</Typography>
              </Popover>
```